# Excel Function to sum values from table based on a comma separated list

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find a function that will look at a table and sum all the values where the string appears in my comma separated list. I can get sumproduct to work if my list is separated into different cells, but I need the list to be in one cell. Here is what I'm looking for:

List in Cell A1:  2000,2100,2300

```
Table: A10:B16

A     B

2000  20

2100  25

2200  32

2300  65

2400  72

2500  12

2600  2
```

I'm looking for a result of: `110`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Excel doesn't allow recursion within a single cell, so you might be out of luck if you don't want VBA and can't use extra columns to pull the individual numbers out.  Are these both real constraints?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid VBA and having to enable macros, etc.  This excel will be passed to several people. Also the list in A1 could have 15-20 items in it. Would be more difficult to maintain that, considering the person that will be updating the data in this worksheet is not very good with excel as it is.

Comment: You can have about 64,000 columns in an Excel sheet, so if you were able to set a maximum number of list items (say, 50), you could do this with helper columns that you hide before sending the sheet off to others.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you can use another column but not for your list?

If so you can use the formula below in column C

=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,$A$1,1))=FALSE,TRUE,FALSE) with A2 being the 1st cell in which the data is contained.

This is searching through your comma separated list and evaluating against the data in column B whether it exists in the list, if so then returns true if not false.

Now you can use the SUMIF function to return those matching true in your new column C.

=SUMIF(C2:C8,TRUE,B2:B8)

If having the evaluation column C is a problem for other users you could always hide it

Comment: I appreciate the help. Looks like I will be using VB.  I can get most of it, but how separating the items in the comma separated list so I can search for each one is giving me a bit of a problem. For the list 2000,2100,2300 I need to be able to search for each of those number and then move on to the next. Any help would be much appreciated.